# Dual run Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit on non- virtualization supported processor

Tags: dual-boot, virtualization

I did try through virtual box machine, running Ubuntu 64bit but error was occured as" no bootable media found system halted" so why I'm trying to dual boot.Is it possible to dual boot windows 10 64bit and ubuntu 64bit on non-virtualization supported processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to shrink the windows partition (or add another disk) for Ubuntu to install on. If you get the normal [Ubuntu media](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), you can start a Live session from it, without installing. This is a good way to try it out, and verify that it runs fine on you machine.

BTW, if you CPU is not very old, it should support HW virtualization. This is often disabled in the BIOS settings of the machine. Have a look the, and see if you can activate it.

Comment: My CPU does not support HW virtualization. I tried running from virtual box and also dual boot but in dual boot it does not shows side by side installation. is the any other way that I can enjoy Ubuntu along with windows 10?

Comment: Can you be more specific on "also dual boot but in dual boot it does not shows side by side installation"? You did install Ubuntu on the disk, but you did get an option to boot in to it? To where did you choose to install the boot loader?